# Converting sqlite3 query to postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I just uploaded my site to Heroku however I got an error in one of my controllers. Apparently I have a syntax error with my postgres code. This works in sqlite3 but when I converted it to postgres a syntax error occurred.

```
   @cars=Car.find_by_sql("SELECT cars.*, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT book_cars.* FROM book_cars WHERE book_cars.car_id=cars.id AND book='t') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END  AS 'is_book' FROM cars WHERE is_book='FALSE'")
```

Any ideas as to what caused the error?
 The error code:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'is_book'"
```

Comment: Try changing `'is_book'` to `is_book` (without the `'`).

Comment: I tried doing that then the error became: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "is_book" does not exist

Comment: And are you sure that the column `is_book` does exist?

Comment: The column book exists. (t.boolean  "book") It works in sqlite3 in my development stage. The error occurs in postgres in my production stage.

Comment: Just to be clear, the column's name is `book` or `is_book`? if you run on your postgres db -> `select is_book from YourTable`, runs ok?

Comment: Its name is book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simple:

```
SELECT *, 'FALSE' As is_book
FROM cars c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM book_cars b
   WHERE b.car_id=c.id AND book = 't'
)
```

you can also use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT cars.*, 
          CASE WHEN EXISTS (
              SELECT book_cars.* FROM book_cars 
              WHERE book_cars.car_id=cars.id AND book='t') 
          THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END  AS is_book
   FROM cars 
) x
WHERE is_book='FALSE';
```

---

**EDIT**

---

The problem in your query is in `WHERE` clause in the last line below:

```
SELECT cars.*, 
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT book_cars.* FROM book_cars 
            WHERE book_cars.car_id=cars.id AND book='t') 
       THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END  AS 'is_book' 
FROM cars 
WHERE is_book='FALSE';
```

In standard SQL `WHERE` clause doesn't see any expression (or "column") declared in the `SELECT` clause, it can only see columns from tables in the `FROM` clause.
`is_book` column is declared in the `SELECT` clause, so `WHERE` cannot see it.
If you use a subquery, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( --- subquery
   SELECT some_expression AS new_column
   FROM ....
) x
WHERE new_column = 111
```

then the outer query sees that new column.

You can also use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT cars.*, 
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT book_cars.* FROM book_cars 
            WHERE book_cars.car_id=cars.id AND book='t') 
       THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END  AS 'is_book' 
FROM cars 
HAVING is_book='FALSE';
```

because `HAVING`, in contrast to `WHERE`, does see columns declared at `SELECT` level.

Comment: This worked thank you very much. If I may ask, what was the problem with my query? I couldn't find what was wrong with it. It worked in Sqlite3.

Comment: I've edited the answer, appended an explanation why `WHERE` doesn't see columns from `SELECT`